# Need to advance slide show pictures with arrow keys

Tags: jquery

how do i advance slide show pictures using the left and right arrow keys. I already have left and right click arrows on screen, but i want the viewer to have both options. I need a script that will work with existing slide show script. What i did so far just put in duplicate pictures underneath the slide show, with no size limits. The arrow keys work, but not with the original slide show pics.

Comment: I think it would be great to show some code.

Comment: OK. This is the code i used for the keyboard arrows.

Comment: <div class="container">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img alt="slideshow" src="file:///Users/johnedgar/Desktop/slideshow%20copy/1.JPG" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" />
    </div>
<script>

Comment: var imgs = [
                "file:///Users/johnedgar/Desktop/slideshow%20copy/1.JPG"
               ];
    function changeImage(dir) {
        var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
        img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
    }
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
        } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            // right -> show next image
            changeImage()
        }
</script>

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

I used this code to make a slideshow. I want to insert code that will allow the viewer to use arrow keys to advance the slides.